# Can someone explain me TTextureStyle.RenderTarget?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

TTexture can have the style `[TTextureStyle.RenderTarget]`

the doc of delphi says:

> Specifies the rendering target for this canvas object.  Use the value
>   of RenderTarget to access the specific properties of the target on
>   which the canvas is drawn. RenderTarget returns a Direct2D interface
>   that can be used directly.

This is a little obscure, can someone explain me exactly the purpose of `TTextureStyle.RenderTarget` and in which condition we need to use it ?

To make the question also useful for everyone, if someone can also explain all the other different values (and their purpose) that TTextureStyle can take :

```
TTextureStyle = (MipMaps, Dynamic, RenderTarget, Volatile);
```

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Types3D.TTextureStyle

Comment: @RudyVelthuis unfortunately it's not help me to understand, what mean tsMipMaps: Multiple textures maps are used. tsDynamic: The texture is accessed dynamically. tsRenderTarget: The source texture is used to render a target. ironically the only value i know is Volatile and it's the only to not be written in the documentation ;)

Comment: TTextureStyle seems to determine how the texture style is generated. You‘ll have to find examples of their use, or read the source code.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes it's pretty obscure this why i think could be useful to have this so question that will answer it

Comment: I personally think the question is too broad.